# How to animate multiple properties using jQuery animation step?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(element).animate(
    {
        scale: 1,
        centerX: -(this.chartObj.model.m_AreaBounds.Width /2),
        centerY:-(this.chartObj.model.m_AreaBounds.Height /2)
    },
    {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(now,fx) {
            var scaleVal, x, y;
            if (fx.prop == "scale") {
                scaleVal = now;
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
            } else if (fx.prop == "centerX") {
                x = now;
                y = 0;
                scaleVal = 0;
            }
            else if (fx.prop == "centerY") {
                x = 0;
                y = now;
                scaleVal = 0;
            }
            $(element).attr("transform", "translate("+x*(scaleVal-1)+","+(y*scaleVal-1)+")scale(" + now + ")");
        }
    }
);
```

In step function prop values will come step by step (ie, first `scale`, then `centerX` and then `centerY`). I want to set all those values using CSS transform property, ie. I want to get all property values in a single step.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `fx` object to store the values off into variables as you step through them, and then use them all at once in the final CSS declaration.

Your problem was setting all the other variables to 0, this can be avoided by instantiating the variables *outside* of the animation function, and then only setting the one variable within each conditional statement. This would allow them to keep their value between iterations.

Here's an example using your code (with just a few alterations to fit the demo better):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
   var scaleVal, x, y;
   scaleVal = x = y = 0;
    
    $({scale: 0, centerX: 0, centerY: 0}).animate({
        scale: 1,
        centerX: 100,
        centerY: 200
    }, {
        duration: 2000,

        step: function (now, fx) {
            if (fx.prop == "scale") {
                scaleVal = now;
            } else if (fx.prop == "centerX") {
                x = now;
            } else if (fx.prop == "centerY") {
                y = now;
            }
            $('div').css("-webkit-transform", "translate(" + x * (scaleVal - 1) + "%," + (y * scaleVal - 1) + "%)scale(" + scaleVal + ")");

        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should animate the element only when all of the properties have a value. This will reduce the number of reflows and create smoother animation.

```js
var animatedProperties = {scale: 0, x: 0, y: 0},
    animatedPropertiesLength = 3,
    updatedProperties = 0,
    targetElement = $('#target');

$({
    scale: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}).animate({
    scale: 1,
    x: 100,
    y: 200
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        animatedProperties[fx.prop] = now;
        
        if (++updatedProperties == animatedPropertiesLength) {
            updatedProperties = 0;
            
            targetElement.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(' + animatedProperties.x * (animatedProperties.scale - 1) + '%,' + (animatedProperties.y * animatedProperties.scale - 1) + '%)scale(' + animatedProperties.scale + ')');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#target {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #bbb;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```